# Oracle-DB: what are the CPU costs of session connect/disconnect

Tags: database, oracle

A generally assessed poor technique is to create an own database session for every atomic DB activity.

You may sometimes encounter such strategies like:

- processing a large amount of items in a loop, each processing step in the loop creates a DB session, executes a small set of SQL statements and terminates the session
- a polling process checks a SQL result one time a second, each in a new DB session

But what costs are generated by frequently connecting and disconnecting DB session?

The internal recording of database activity (AWR/ASH) has no answer because establishing the DB connection is not a SQL activity.

Answer (score 2):

A simple comparison of system load gives a fuzzy hint to the price of connection creation.

Example:

- An idle database instance on a single host with 4 older CPU cores (Intel Xeon E312xx, 2,6 GHz)
- a external (not on DB host) SQLPlus client which executes a single "SELECT SYSTIMESTMP FROM DUAL" per DB session
- Delay between the SQLPlus calls is time so that 1 connection per second is created and destroyed.
- 6 Threads active each with 1 session creation per second

Result:

- with idle database CPU load over 4 CPU nodes is in average 0.22%
- with 6 threads creating and destroying sessions each second CPU load is 6.09%
- io wait also occurs with 1.07% in average
- so in average 5.87% of 4 CPU nodes are allocated by this 6 threads
- Equivalent to 23.48% of one CPU node for 6 threads or 3,91% per thread

**That means:**

**Connecting and disconnecting an Oracle DB session once per second costs approximately 4% of a CPU core of DB server.**

This value in mind should help to consider if it's worth to change process behavior regarding session creation or not.

p.s.: This does not consider the additional cost of session creation at client side.

Answer (score 1):

The superficial practical answer depends how you define 'connection' - is a connection what the app knows as a connection, or is it the network connection to the DB, or is it the DB server process & memory used to do any processing?  The theoretical overall answer is that the process of establishing some application context and starting a DB server process with some memory allocation included - and then doing the reverse when the app has finished running SQL statements - is 'expensive'.  This was measured in Peter Ramm's answer.

In practice, long running applications that expect to handle a number of users would create a connection pool (e.g. in [Node.js](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#createpool) or in [Python](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.SessionPool)).  These remain open for the life of the application.  From the application's point of view, getting a connection from the pool to do some SQL is a very quick operation.  The initial cost (a few seconds of startup at most) of creating the connection pool can be amortized over the process life of the application.

The number of server processes (and therefore overhead costs) on the database tier can be reduced by additional use of a ['Database Resident Connection Pool'](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/performance-and-scalability.html#GUID-0B0DC596-17FF-4EEE-BAA1-9F428710C1AC).

These connection pools have other benefits for Oracle in terms of supporting Oracle's High Availability features, often transparently.  But that's off topic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, you are completely right in mentioning connection pooling as preferred solution.

Comment: My pain point from a DBA perspective was to decide up to what level the frequency of dedicated DB session creation is negligible and when should you start to force a different application behavior (like using connection pools).

Comment: It was interesting to see the results.   I think the HA benefits of Oracle's session pooling also plays a role in the final decision. And then there is how the app uses each connection to be factored in.